# Align enumerate and itemize environment left

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

How can I align the left hand side of *both* the enumerate and the itemize environments to be the same?

That is, I want to set the lengths such that the blue vertical line and the red vertical line in the pic below will be the same.

[image]

MWE:

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
  \setlist[itemize]{wide,labelindent=0pt,listparindent=0pt,leftmargin=*}
  \setlist[enumerate]{wide,labelindent=0pt,listparindent=0pt,label = \alph*.,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

Your text goes here.

\begin{itemize}
\item Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus. Odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.

Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus.
\item Blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl.
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet.
\item Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet.

Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you used additional options in the `enumerate` list? Any solution would break down if you do that.

Comment: @schtandard Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "additional options". Do you mean that I "over defined" some settings?

Comment: I mean the options after `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: Thats right, I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    \usepackage{enumitem}
      \setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, labelsep=1.6em, listparindent=0pt,leftmargin=*}%,labelindent
      \setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, labelsep=-0.5em ,listparindent=0pt,label = \alph*.,leftmargin=*}%,labelindent

    \begin{document}

    \section{First section}

    Your text goes here.

    \begin{itemize}
    \item Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus. Odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.

    Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus.
    \item Blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl.
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{enumerate}[align=left,labelwidth=\parindent,labelsep=10pt]
    \item Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet.
    \item Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet.

    Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien.
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I believe you should set the parameter `leftmargin` to the same width -- e.g., 15pt -- for both envrironments.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=15pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=15pt, label=\alph*.}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

Your text goes here.

\begin{itemize}
\item Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus. Odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.

Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus.
\item Blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl.
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet.
\item Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet.

Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```